# how to insert Timestamp field using code First in EF

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, timestamp, code-first

I have Timestamp field type VARBINARY I want to ask how I should insert byte[] on Timestamp field using code first

```
private void AddDataToFormsTable(AthenaContext context)
{
    List<Form> listOfForms = new  List<Form>( )
                                 {
                                     new Form(){ UniqeId = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Form", Description = "form", ModifiedBy = " ",ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now,CreatedBy = " ",CreatedOn = DateTime.Now},
                                     new Form(){ UniqeId = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Form2", Description = "form2", ModifiedBy = " ",ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now,CreatedBy = " ",CreatedOn = DateTime.Now},
                                     new Form(){ UniqeId = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Form3", Description = "form3", ModifiedBy = " ",ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now,CreatedBy = " ",CreatedOn = DateTime.Now},
                                     new Form(){ UniqeId = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Form4", Description = "form4", ModifiedBy = " ",ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now,CreatedBy = " ",CreatedOn = DateTime.Now},
                                     new Form(){ UniqeId = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Form5", Description = "form5", ModifiedBy = " ",ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now,CreatedBy = " ",CreatedOn = DateTime.Now},
                                 };

    listOfForms.ForEach(i =>context.Forms.Add(i));

    context.SaveChanges();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution, change the type of CreatedOn to DateTime in your database,

otherwise: `Convert.ToByte(DateTime.Now)`